# Ошибка "element type is invalid" при импортировании в react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Пытаюсь импортировать компонент и получаю ошибку:

> "element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function".

Основной файл *index.android.js*:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import {Text2} from './components/Text2';

class p001_lesson extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text2/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('p001_lesson', () => p001_lesson);
```

Второй файл *Text2.js*:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
} from 'react-native';


class Text2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return some text here
    }
}
```

Как исправить импорт?

Answer (score 0):

Для использования компонента Text2 в другом файле его необходимо экспортировать:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


class Text2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>some text here</Text>
  }
}

export default Text2;
```

И в файле index.android.js подключить следующей строкой:

```
import Text2 from './components/Text2';
```